# Ender breaks requirejs optimiser

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, ender

I am using ender to create a drop in replacement for my jquery usage.

I am using just `qwery`, `bean` and `bonzo` (no need for dom ready in my use case), and everything works fine. I include the ender dev build as a path in my require config, and a shim to export it to the `$` symbol, and in dev mode that works fine.

The problem comes from when I build. I am using the grunt build task that ships with Yeoman Backbone generator. What seems to happen is my require modules 'config' method no longer exists, I think something in Ender overwrites `require` with something else (possibly `browserify` or some other AMD loader?)

Is there a fix or work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround at this point is to find and replace the word 'require' for something else (I went with 'loadModule')

Bit hacky, but it's working for now.